# Is there a way to check if a map has been initialized in C++98?

Tags: c++

I am running into a problem in a very large coding project I'm doing. In one function I need to iterate through a map and insert some things but the way the program works is that the first couple times through the map isn't initialized yet and I cannot initialize it in that function because it is initialized else where where it needs to be. So the problem is the first couple of times through when I try to iterate through the map and it is not yet initialized the program crashes. I was googling and so forth looking for a way to test if map has been initialized before continuing with that section of the code. The way I verified the problem is by bypassing that segment of code for the first 5k cycles. This works for this particular benchmark but this isn't a robust method and I need something that will work for a lot of different benchmarks. Thanks in advance.

```
if(map_is_initialized>=5000)
{
    for(std::map<RAddr, uint32_t>::iterator it = f_read_Prediction_Set->begin(); it !=    f_read_Prediction_Set->end(); ++it)
    {
        set = (((it->first) >> log2AddrLs) & maskSets) << log2Assoc;
        if(set == caddr)
            (*currentSets)[set] = 1;

    }
}

map_is_initialized+=1;
```

Comment: By "initialized" you mean to check that it is non-null?

Comment: i mean that it has been created....i.e. "std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >* f_read_Prediction_Set = new std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >;"

Comment: What triggers the initialization? If it is being done in a separate thread; perhaps a simple `while (!map_initialized) ;` optionally with whatever your platform's equivalent of `yield()` is thrown in there. Or, more appropriately, a proper condition variable.

Comment: it is created in a different function, i want to get away from the map_is_initialized int if possible

Comment: @JazzyBelle Something is missing in the information you are giving us. The fact that it seems to be happening asynchronously suggests that it is happening in another thread, in which case proper synchronization should be implemented. If that is not the case, and it is created by a different function but not on a different thread, then can you not just call that function to initialize the map? (In the latter case, your 5k loop seems to contradict, unless retrieving/incrementing the iterator is what is building the map, or there is some other code you are not showing). We need more information.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's a map pointer, 
If you've access to the class's constructor, Initialize it to NULL
If you don't have, try to initialize it to NULL in an early called function or subclass's constructor

Later on, you can check if it's not NULL

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. Depending on what is going on, you have options:

If it is as simple as some other code prior to that loop is building the map, you could:

- Run the other code until the map is initialized before you enter the benchmark loop.
- Either initialize the map pointer to NULL or use some "initialized" flag, and do not process the data if the pointer is NULL or the flag is not set.

If it is being done in a separate thread; a proper event / condition variable would do the trick, or whatever equivalent of `while (!map_initialized) yield();` you have.